# Child record accessing other child records via the parent record in after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  after_create :alert_another_order_created

  def alert_another_order_created
    return if user.orders.count > 1
    puts "More code here"
  end
end
```

In another place I call it in the following matter:

```
User.find_or_create_by_email('user@email.com').orders.find_or_create_by_product('bleh')
```

It works on my local environment and in testing. However in the production environment I keep getting the following exception:

```
undefined method `orders' for nil:NilClass
```

The exception refers to Order#alert_another_order_created (the `return` line)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Order` record doesn't have its `user` associated, so `Order#user` in this case returns `nil`. If you need every order to be associated with user, you can validate user's presence:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  # ...
end
```